# Antonym of "time-critical" or "time-sensitive"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

I'm looking for a word or phrase to indicate that something does not need to be rushed/expedited. That isn't to say the subject is unimportant, but merely not sensitive to time.

I am using this to talk about spacecraft transit times to other planets. Human-crewed spaceflights are time-critical, since they consume resources every day in space. Cargo, on the other hand, doesn't need a strict timeline, so long as it arrives in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: I know this sounds too simple, but how about _non-time-critical_ and/or _non-time-sensitive?_

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Granted, this is probably the most obvious choice, but I was hoping for something less hyphenated and more terse.

Comment: Well, you could have one of your characters introduce the term:  "If it matters when it gets there it's a chron load; if it doesn't it's nonchron.

Comment: By the way, any kind of cargo is expected sometime, somebody is paying for it and waiting for it. Here's a word about the time-is-money aspect of shipping and receiving:  http://www.google.com/search?q=demurrage+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en

Comment: In the UK, [***'hospital job'** is builder's slang for a project that's worked on only when there's nothing better to do*](http://guernseypress.com/news/2006/11/03/questions-asked-about-minsters-role/). Years ago I saved a lot of money by letting the builders work on my extension when it suited them. They took over 6 months for what could have been completed in as many weeks, but it was a good arrangement for both parties.

Comment: I just wrote an answer for *unexpedited*, and noticed *expedited* is in your question.  What's the issue with *unexpedited*?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Though having a character introduce a phrase would work in fiction, I'm using it in real life. I don't have creative license to invent jargon. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, that's a good phrase! I've never heard an alternate for '_busy work_'. Unfortunately, this is for scientific work, so slang is inappropriate.

Comment: @stevesliva I'm having a hard time finding a definition for 'unexpedited'. To me, that sounds like the opposite of rushing something: to make something take _longer_ than it would normally. This isn't what I'm going for.

Comment: The Yankee equivalent to 'hospital job' might be 'busy work' (see above).  However, 'busy work' isn't necessary scheduled; it's just always "there".  In meetings we have, work is prioritized.  "Not a priority" is common phrase used to dismiss those thing not important ... in the time scheme of things anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the item is ***deferrable*** to indicate that the item does not require immediate attention.

> :  capable of or suitable or eligible for being deferred
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deferrable)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Delay tolerant?

Time independent?

Answer (score 0):

nonurgent or asynchronous? I realize that doesn't quite capture "reasonable period of time" aspect of your meaning, but thought it might trigger someone else to have an idea.  I was surprised to find that nonurgent appears to be somewhat commonly used...

Comment: An answer will be much better accepted if sources for the information  supplied. is cited.